# Find a Value in a cell QT Table Widget by having row number and column number in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I have a QT Table Widget in python where I find the row number and the column number of the last item changed by the user in this way :

```
class elencoviaggi(QtWidgets.QDialog):
 def __init__(self):
    super(elencoviaggi, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('elenco_viaggi.ui', self)
    self.tabella_registrazioni.setColumnWidth(0, 30)
    self.tabella_registrazioni.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
    self.botton = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'pushButton_3') 
    self.botton.clicked.connect(self.salva) !

 def salva(self): 
    print(self.tabella_registrazioni.itemChanged.connect(self.changeIcon))   
 def changeIcon(self, item):
    row = item.row()
    col = item.column()
```

In this part of the code I correctly find through a button the row number and the column number of the last item changed by the user, how can I store in a variable the item that has column 0 and as row the "row" variable declared? I tried this tabella_registrazioni.Item(row, 0) but doesn't work.
I don't know what is the command to find an item using row and column numbers

Comment: It's [`item()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#item), with a *lowercase* "i". Also, you should not connect a signal multiple times (as you're doing in `salva` every time the button is clicked).

Comment: I tried item(row, 0) but it returns me this errrore " value= item(row, 0)
TypeError: 'QTableWidgetItem' object is not callable"

Comment: `item` is the argument, you have to call the *function* of the table: `self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 0)`.

Comment: yeah that worked, I used .text() to convert it into text, btw what do you mean to not connect a signal multiple times? Should I connect it one time (when I visualize the table for the first time)? And if I connect it one time, If I'd like to add the value changed into sql server with that signal, will it be added everytime the signal "goes on" or just the first time?

Comment: A function is called for *every* connection made to the signal. If you connect a function to a signal twice, when that signal is emitted, the function will be called twice. The `itemChanged` signal is emitted *every time* **any** item is changed, not only the first time. Please check the documentation about signals and slots to understand how they work and how they should be used.

Comment: Please take your time to review the [tour] and read [ask], sorry but this is not a forum, comments should always be in topic with the original post. If you have another *unrelated* question, create a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same issue the command is :

```
self.yourtablename.item(therownumber, thecolumnnumber)
```